# How to disable external access to an overlay network in a docker swarm

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up a swarm that has the following services:

- nginx as a reverse proxy (mostly to deal with virtual hosts and SSL, though that's not in the nginx.conf).
- a golang web app.
- redis for caching.
- postgresql for storage.

This leads to a docker-compose file similar to:

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.13.5-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - webnet

  api:
    image: user/webapp:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 4
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    networks:
      - webnet

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.5-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet

  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.2-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

The nginx config file I'm using is:

```
upstream api {
    server api:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}
```

This is all working. I can connect from another machine using curl and the nginx service proxies to the respective webapp services.

The problem is, I can also connect to the redis, api and postgres services from the external machine.

What I want is to make only the proxy service accessible from an external interface.

I want to make sure that the redis, api and postgres services are only accessible via the swarm. (or, accessible only on the local network of host node. In this case, the host is CentOS 7 set up as the swarm manager).

Instead of using webnet, I tried creating an overlay network called backend that sets `internal` to `true`. Something like this:

```
docker network create -d overlay --internal backend
```

The `backend` network was then used in the docker-compose.yml file instead of webnet for redis, postgres and api services. This didn't seem to work. all services were still available on the external ip.

I can work around this issue by:

- Blocking the ports for the services I don't want to expose.
- Doing the above and also running nginx as a proxy on the host machine (not as a container).

While the above does work, I'd really prefer that all this logic be enforced at the docker-compose level, and not rely on firewall or external processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want the ports accessible externally, then you do not need to publish those ports. Containers can always talk container to container over a common docker network without the port being published.

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.13.5-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - webnet

  api:
    image: user/webapp:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    networks:
      - webnet

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.5-alpine
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet

  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.2-alpine
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for digging this up but I have one related question. In my code, I call the containers by name and port - like `connect redis:6379`. If I block port access, would I be able to call the service only with `connect redis`?

Comment: @GustavoSilva This is still TCP networking, so you need to connect to a port. The other container may be listening on multiple ports depending on the app running in that container. Depending on that app you use to connect from, it may already know the default redis port and use that if you don't specify, but that's client app specific.